# Google Play Store insufficient storage error

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I own a rooted Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (GT-P3110). Im using Android 4.2.2 and Cyanogenmod 10.1.3-p3110.

Since a few days my tablets play store screws up installing some apps. I get an insufficient storage error after the installprocess starts everytime (when the download has ended). This occurred with youtube but strangely enough not with some barcodescanner app. When I look at my usage of internal storage however there seems to be more than 2 gigs of free space left.

The internet is full of people getting this error. I tried many solutions, but none of them seem to work. I tried to wipe the cache and dalvik cache. Also I tried to look at the free internal storage in different ways. Nothing seems to work. However I can put apks on my tablet via usb and then install them without any problems. This isnt really practical though.

Also updates are going fine too. I dont get this error when apps update automatically.

[image: Error log during youtube install]
[image: Evidence #1]
[image: Evidence #2]
[image: Evidence #3]
[image: Error popping up in play store]

**Edit:** Also tried to fix permissions in Clockwordmod Recovery, didn't help
**Edit 2:** A copy of df command in terminal

```
u0_a40@android:/ $ su
u0_a40@android:/ # df
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/dev                   387.4M    48K   387.3M   4096
/storage               387.4M     0K   387.4M   4096
/storage/emulated      387.4M     0K   387.4M   4096
/storage/sdcard1        23.9G    32K    23.9G   16384
/mnt/secure            387.4M     0K   387.4M   4096
/mnt/asec              387.4M     0K   387.4M   4096
/mnt/obb               387.4M     0K   387.4M   4096
/mnt/fuse              387.4M     0K   387.4M   4096
/system                  1.3G   374.9M  1003.1M   4096
/efs                    19.7M     4.1M    15.5M   4096
/data                    4.6G     2.5G     2.1G   4096
/cache                 689M    70M   619M   4096
/mnt/shell/emulated      4.6G     2.5G     2.1G   4096
/storage/emulated/0      4.6G     2.5G     2.1G   4096
/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb     4.6G     2.5G     2.1G   4096
/storage/emulated/legacy     4.6G     2.5G     2.1G   4096
/storage/emulated/legacy/Android/obb     4.6G     2.5G     2.1G   4096
u0_a40@android:/ #
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up flashing a new rom. I am using Slimkat 4.4.4 now and had to flash it using the latest Philz Touch which I found right here https://goo.im/devs/philz_touch/CWM_Advanced_Edition/p3110/

The problem now seems to have been solved, although I didnt prefer this particular solution. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to settings->Apps->Running Apps and select "Google Play Services" click on uninstall latest updates and things should work again.This is a bug from google play and it creates multiple copies of your app directory in memory.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this doesn't seem to help :(

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on further possibilities? Please note my edits.

Answer (score 1):

Going to Settings > Apps > Choose Google Play Services and then Clear Cache, worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only known "solution" for non-rooted devices whose cache and app data have already been wiped is to apply a factory reset.

If you change your mind and decide to root your phone, I suggest you install Android SDK Tools Only on your computer, then root your phone, go to Android's Settings, then Developer Options, then activate USB Debugging. After you do this, use a USB cable to connect your Android device to the computer where you installed the SDK tools.

The SDK tools have ADB (Android debugger). Open a shell window, go to the folder where the SDK tools were installed, look for a folder named platform-tools and access it. Inside this folder there will be an executable binary file named adb (or adb.exe, if you're using Windows). Then run the following command in order to make ADB access the command prompt of your Android device:

adb shell
Now that you're in your Android device shell (commands interpreter), run this command in order to become root (also known as superuser):

su -
Afterwards, run this command to check what's your system's default APK install location:

pm get-install-location
If the command above returns 2, it means that the Android package manager (pm) is incorrectly configured to install APKs in your external storage (e.g. microSD card) instead of in your device's internal storage (which is the correct one).

In order to fix it, run this command:

pm set-install-location 1
1 means internal storage media.

Now restart your device with this command:

reboot